# Modelling Population with Stochastic Model and a Random Variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have this stochastic model: N(t+1)=(1+r^3)N(t), where r is a random variable from a Normal Population with mean= -0.1 and standard deviation=0.2.

I'm trying to make a histogram from 1000 samples of this random that will model my population, and I've tried a few things to no avail.

So far I have:

```
import numpy as np 
import numpy.random as npr 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
npr.seed(101)

N = np.zeros(11)
N[0]=100
tvec = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
r = npr.normal(loc=2,scale=3, size=1000)

for t in tvec[:10]:
    N[t+1]=(1+r**3)+N[t]

plt.hist(N)
```

but that gives me an error.

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),
>   numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Which tells me that I'm not able to take the random numbers I'm sampling and use them in my equation.

So, I'm wondering if there's a different way I could be going about this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you point out the line which threw that error please?

Comment: @Arthur-1 it was `N[t+1]=(1+r**3)+N[t]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because `t` is a float and initially has a value of 0.0. If you try `N[0.0]` you can reproduce the error. You can use integers rather than floats. Also, I changed `r` to `r_values` and zipped it to `t` so the loop works only on single values for `r` and `t` rather than an array for `r`.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as npr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

npr.seed(101)

N = np.zeros(11)
N[0]=100
tvec = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
r_values = npr.normal(loc=2,scale=3, size=10)

for t,r in zip(tvec, r_values):
    #print(t,r)
    N[t+1]=(1+r**3)+N[t]

plt.hist(N)
```

[image]